# What is the motivation for the Self-Dual Canonical Anticommutation Relation (CAR) algebra?

Tags: condensed-matter, commutator, lattice-model, clifford-algebra, anticommutator

What exactly is the motivation for the use of the Self-Dual Canonical Anticommutation Relation (CAR) algebra in the context of infinite lattice systems? Why not remain with the CAR algebra, as both are in some sense $^*$-isomorphic to one another.

Comment: What is the  "Self-Dual Canonical Anticommutation Relation"?  How does it differ from the usual CAR?

Comment: Definition 3.1, 2.1, respectively found in https://ems.press/content/serial-article-files/2485

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no difference between the usual CAR and the "self dual" CAR except for the language in which it is packaged.

Looking at a more [recent  paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.05069.pdf), the packaging seems  to be just  the map between the conventional CAR  and and an orthogonal Clifford algebra. The authors  cite
[Fujikawa](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.05069.pdf)   to suggest  that it is just Nambu's "doubling the Hilbert space" formalism. Given an ${\rm O}(2n)$-based   Clifford algebra one can rewrite it as a CAR algebra, but this rewriting  depends on the choice of an orthogonal complex structure on $2n$-dimensional real vector space. The resulting set of "vacuum" vectors for the CAR is the set of possible ground states  for the Fermion bilinear Hamiltonians and can be identified  the Cartan symmetric space ${\rm SO}(2n)/{\rm U}(n)$. This becomes  ${\rm O}(2n)/{\rm U}(n)$ in the topologically no-trivial sector.

Sadly this observation  does not help  your question about  infinite systems which was  the motivation for Araki's original introduction of the "self dual" idea.  The infinite CAR have many inequivalent representations, but  what the advantage of Araki's definition is unclear to me. It is more about functional analysis than alegbra and I am out of my depth there. I find Araki's text rather impenetrable.